# Open local video on Android device, from a QR code

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code

**Background**

Some teams in my company's facilities are using Android tablets for multiple operations. We would like to allow them to access video demos from their tablets, when they are at specific places in the facility, without having to search through the tablet for the right video. So we thought of QR codes (printed on paper, stuck to the wall). Problem is: for security reasons, we can't allow the devices to access any network.

**Question**

So the idea is to store the videos locally, and have the QR code route to the local file. I thought this would be easy but it doesn't appear to be.

I have generated QR codes like `file:///path/to/my/file.mp4`, also trying to play with intents, like this:
`file:///path/to/my/file.mp4#Intent;scheme=file;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;type=video/mp4;end`.

(+ variants including `intent://`, using `scheme=file`, targeting images instead of videos...)

In the best cases, the browser opens, closes, and I receive *"Cannot display `file`. Invalid PDF"*, and in the worst cases, *"Sorry, the application could not be launched. The bar code content may be invalid."*.

I also tried variants (images instead of videos, URL vs plain text QR codes, several code scanner applications), all with the same result. I have searched through SO, but most questions are about doing this programmatically in an application, while I would like to avoid designing an app just for this.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there no way to do this that way?**

Note: I had absolutely no knowledge about Android and intents before trying to solve this case, there may be smarter workarounds. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah but what have you actually done? Are you programming an app that does these operations? or you're expecting that by putting the files into the devices and a random QR app wire everything and just work?

Comment: I'm looking for the most simple solution, so hopefully without having to write an app. Ideally I would only have to generate QR codes, readable by a given QR app (any free app would work, I just need to figure out one which works). The answer can be that it's not possible (or not practical), in which case I would consider creating the app, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Given the network requirement within your company, it seems building a simple application is the easiest solution(maybe because I am an app developer).

So your app would need only 2 screens. QR code Scanner and a View that shows the video.(once you click done, go back to scanning)

The app can have all the videos you need prebuilt in the app itself and the QR codes can be the names of those videos.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't know if you are using web page or any android app for this fature, for web page you need to create your own scanner or integrate ready made solution [i found 1 here](https://medium.com/@minhazav/qr-code-scanner-using-html-and-javascript-3895a0c110cd), you will need setTimeinterval so it scans bar code once, Once barcode is found you will need to call your ajax method to fetch complete URL of that video, once any item is returned, you need to display it in iframe.
Hope it works for you.